# Piecewise optimization gurobi

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

Following is a piecewise function. I need to optimize it. q is the decision variable while the objective is to minimize the overall function subject to the constraint that it never gets zero.

[image]

How can I optimize this piecewise. all other variables other than q are constant values.

Answer (score 0):

Using `y(t,m,i) = q(t,m,i) + eps/MI`, and `ln(a/b)=ln(a)-ln(b)` there are two terms to worry about:

```
 f(y(t,m,i)) = y(t,m,i) ln y(t,m,i)
```

and

```
 g(y(t,m,i),y(t-1,m,i)) =  y(t,m,i) ln y(t-1,m,i)
```

The first one is easy. The second one not so much, see [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/09/2d-sos2.html) for some notes.

Comment: How is the first one easy??

Comment: I assumed it was somewhat obvious that piecewise approximation of f(x,y) is much more difficult than of f(x).

Comment: I am sorry to say, that is quite a nonsensical piece of code. `setPWLOb` is not supposed to return anything. Please consult the Gurobi documentation and the examples. I think you are missing some concepts here. It may be a good idea to talk to your teacher.

Comment: how does a the setPWLObj is linked with overall cost?

Comment: Can you give me some comments like the ones mentioned in the answer of this link .
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gurobi/YUWqUfk3PSc